# Why and how does the [elasticsearch] tag have a logo?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [[elasticsearch]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/elasticsearch/info) tag looks like the following:

[image: elasticsearch tag from StackOverflow. The tag has a small logo]

This is the only tag I've seen with a logo, hosted here: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUiNP.png)

- Why does it have a logo?
- Should other tags have logos?

Comment: they are called sponsored tag https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sponsored-tags

Comment: This does, thank you! I knew there had to be a word for it, but I couldn't find "sponsored tag" when searching for logos, etc.